# How to gobally change the color of hyperlinks in a pdf document?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I have a document (specifically a scientific paper) with colored hyperlinks. Now from [this question](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-discussions/changing-hypertext-link-color/td-p/10997094), I understand that it's actually not the hyperlinks that are colored, but in fact the text underneath. But is there nevertheless any way to globally/automatically change the text color of all the text elements with a hyperlink?

Comment: I think this is not possible to do in Acrobat. You can change the text color but to my knowledge, there is not a way to select all by fill color, or select by another method.